# How to fetch data from 2 csv files in swift

Tags: swift, csv, annotations, mapkit

My app currently gets data (points on map) from the .csv file San Francisco.

What should I change in my code to get data from San Francisco as well as Oakland, another .csv file that I have added?

```
func setupData() {
pointsDataSource = PointsDataSource(with: "San Francisco")

//if let pointsDataSource = pointsDataSource {
//map.addAnnotations(pointsDataSource.annotations)
//}
}
```

[image]

Comment: My app already scans .csv file. I only ask, how can it scan from 2 files instead of one. There must be a small change on m code to make it work but i'm a newbie

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different methods for scanning a CSV file into your app using Swift. I found that I was able to create my own class method that I thought was the most useful.

I have to apologise because I haven't referenced the internet posts by other developers that helped me out - If I come accross them again then I'll definitely include them!

Here is the class:

```
import Foundation

class CSVScanner {

class func debug(string:String){

    println("CSVScanner: \(string)")
}

class func runFunctionOnRowsFromFile(theColumnNames:Array<String>, withFileName theFileName:String, withFunction theFunction:(Dictionary<String, String>)->()) {

    if let strBundle = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(theFileName, ofType: "csv") {

        var encodingError:NSError? = nil

        if let fileObject = NSString(contentsOfFile: strBundle, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &encodingError){

            var fileObjectCleaned = fileObject.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\r", withString: "\n")

            fileObjectCleaned = fileObjectCleaned.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\n\n", withString: "\n")

            let objectArray = fileObjectCleaned.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")

            for anObjectRow in objectArray {

                let objectColumns = anObjectRow.componentsSeparatedByString(",")

                var aDictionaryEntry = Dictionary<String, String>()

                var columnIndex = 0

                for anObjectColumn in objectColumns {

                    aDictionaryEntry[theColumnNames[columnIndex]] = anObjectColumn.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\"", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch, range: nil)

                    columnIndex++
                }

                if aDictionaryEntry.count>1{
                    theFunction(aDictionaryEntry)
                }else{

                    CSVScanner.debug("No data extracted from row: \(anObjectRow) -> \(objectColumns)")
                }
            }
        }else{
            CSVScanner.debug("Unable to load csv file from path: \(strBundle)")

            if let errorString = encodingError?.description {

                CSVScanner.debug("Received encoding error: \(errorString)")
            }
        }
    }else{
        CSVScanner.debug("Unable to get path to csv file: \(theFileName).csv")
    }
  }
}
```

> You can implement it in your code like this:

```
var myCSVContents = Array<Dictionary<String, String>>()

CSVScanner.runFunctionOnRowsFromFile(["title", "body", "category"],    withFileName: "fileName.csv", withFunction: {

    (aRow:Dictionary<String, String>) in

    myCSVContents.append(aRow)

})
```

This will build an array of Dictionary objects, each representing a row from the CSV. You need to supply an array as the first parameter which contains the header labels of your csv document - make sure you include a label for every column!

However, feel free to skip adding the rows to an Array - you can run any function you like on each row. For instance, you may want to add these directly into a CoreData object.